# Is Web Share API broken on Chrome + Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, chromium, web-share

My code is similar to many examples on the web, including MDN code at https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-share/

```
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navigator.share(shareData)
          .then(() =>
            console.log('MDN shared successfully');
          )
          .catch((e) =>
            console.error('Error: ' + e);
          )
      });
```

Issue:

`navigator.share` returns a promise supposed to fail if sharing is denied. In my case it does so, but after several seconds of delay.
My main problem is this delay: I can fallback if I know sharing API is failing, except here I need to wait for an unknown amount of time before the error.

Mode details:

- The error is "Error: AbortError: Share canceled"
- I did not cancel anything (I see no UI before the error happens). Maybe Windows denied something without displaying any message.
- I am using Windows 8.1 Pro, this could be related.
- Same problem for me with Chrome 90.0.4430.93 (and previous version 89.0.4389.128), but also with Edge (89.0.774.54 Official build 64-bit)
- delay is longer than 20 seconds (disconnecting internet access does not change that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the [demo](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-share/) on Windows 10 on both Chrome and Edge (Stable), and it worked. Maybe an extension is interfering with the API?

[image: MDN demo showing Web Share in action]

Comment: Right. Thanks, it helps: looks like "something outside Chromium". But probably not an extension since I just found out Edge is having the same problem on my machine. I will edit my question too. A bit sad if this just becomes a "Win 8.1" does it wrong, but well...

Comment: Any idea about which browser settings can interfere is welcome. I disabled extensions and allowed "pop-ups", just in case; no improvement from that.
BTW @DenverCoder9, I tried to "vote up" your answer but cannot since I don't have the "reputation" to do it (even for my own question, sigh...)

Comment: Using BrowserStack and Edge 90 on Windows 8.1, I could indeed confirm the behavior you describe in your post. Seems like a Windows issue then. FWIW, I checked Edge 90's native system menu on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, and on 8.1 it lacks the Share option. Compare [Windows 8.1](https://snipboard.io/NQw4lg.jpg) to [Windows 10](https://snipboard.io/qkWZC1.jpg).

Comment: You are right; looks like Windows 8.1 has been left behind... Thank you for detailed investigation!

Comment: On windows 11, the windows open, load but close after 1 or 2 seconds, any idea ?